# Stop thread in libgdx - java

Tags: java, multithreading, libgdx

If I'm not mistaken in Java, a Thread can be blocked in two ways:

- sleep (n seconds);

- wait () and notify ()

Using libgdx how can I block and then unlock a thread?

Comment: Same way as with anything else in Java. If you are a beginner with LibGDX, you almost certainly should not be messing with threads.

Comment: my intention was to put the game and all its elements on pause

Comment: Give your game states. When in pause state, don't update the gameplay simulation. If you have nothing animated during pause, you can also use Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false) to save some battery. Turn it back on when ending pause state.